# Set value jquery work in trace but doesn't work without trace

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

I have set filter in Kendo grid but i have a problem when filter applied to grid, i missed value of my filter row.
[image]

After filter i missed my filter :
[image]

Now for this reason, i set my filter row again so bellow code :

```
function updateSearchFilters(grid, field, operator, value) 
{
var newFilter = { field: field, operator: operator, value: value };
var dataSource = grid.dataSource;
var filters = null;
if ( dataSource.filter() != null)
{
    filters = dataSource.filter().filters;
}       
if ( filters == null ) 
{
    filters = [newFilter];
}
else 
{
    var isNew = true;
    var index = 0;
    for(index=0; index < filters.length; index++) 
    {
        if (filters[index].field == field) 
        {
            isNew = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( isNew)
    {
        filters.push(newFilter);
    }
    else 
    {
        //alert(value);
        if(value == '')
            filters.splice(index,1);
            //delete filters[index];
        else
            filters[index] = newFilter;
    }
}
 dataSource.filter(filters);
for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
    $('#gridId-filter-column-' +  filters[i].field.toString()).val(filters[i].value.toString());
}
}
```

When i set the break point in this line  $('#gridId-filter-column-' +  filters[i].field.toString()).val(filters[i].value.toString()); it worked correct but
when i remove break point this line doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set delay before run this line :

```
 for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {    $('#gridId-filter-column-' +filters[i].field.toString()).val(filters[i].value.toString());      }
```